# Cant write into mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

I worked years with HTML, JS and CSS and now need to go further with MySql(for which I use localhost phpMyAdmin) and PHP. I am trying to send data to my database. But I get no errors and I don't know what's wrong.
Heres my register.php:

```
    <?php
    include('classes/db.php');
    
    if (isset($_POST['createaccount'])) {
      $username = $_POST['username'];
      $email = $_POST['email'];
      $password = $_POST['password'];
    
      db::query('INSERT INTO users VALUES (\'\', :username, :email, :password)', array(':username'=>$username, ':email'=>$email, ':password'=>$password));
      echo "Success!";
    }
    ?>
    
    <h1>REGISTER</h1>
    <form action="register.php" method="post">
      <input type="text" name"username" vlaue="" placeholder="Username">
      <input type="email" name"email" vlaue="" placeholder="E-Mail">
      <input type="password" name"password" vlaue="" placeholder="Password">
      <input type="submit" name"createaccount" vlaue="Register">
    </form>
```

And here is my db.php, svaed under classes/db.php:

```
<?php
class db {
  private static function connect() {
    //db inf, username, pwd
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=emergencybase;charset=utf8', 'root', '');
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    return $pdo;
  }

  public static function query($query, $params = array()) {
    $statement = self::connect()->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute($params);
    //$data = $statement->fetchAll();
    //return $data;
  }
}
```

I get no errors and in my database absolutely appears nothing:
Database users:

[image]

Hope someone can help me out of this.
~Marius :)

Comment: You sure, you're not getting errors when executing your query. Your query seems incomplete (missing a closing parenthesis and a terminator).

Comment: @HellBringer419 yeah. Not in the console in dev tools and even not anywhere on the screen. Or is there an extra console for PHP errors?

Comment: Nah .. I don't think so. I mean there is one more but you should have received a warning. So probably not

Comment: As mentioned in the answer the `name` attributes are missing the `=`, plus the attribute `vlaue` should be `value`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Wrong syntax for `name` attributes. It should be `name="email"` not `name"email"`, same goes for all. You aren't getting any error because the code is not even executed, `$_POST['createaccount']` not being set.
2. In your `INSERT INTO` query you should also specify the column names, so the query becomes `INSERT INTO users (username, email, password) VALUES (:username, :email, :password)` , assuming you have an autoincrement `id` primary key on your table.

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer. Now it works. Thanks. But I have one problem left. Currently, my query looks like this: `db::query('INSERT INTO users (id, username, email, password) VALUES (\'\', :username, :email, :password)', array(':username'=>$username, ':email'=>$email, ':password'=>$password));`  But when I look into my database the id field is 0 every time. That's a problem because every user needs a unique id.

Comment: i am taking a wild guess that your id is an integer AUTO INCREMENT primary key. this means that you don't have to include it in your insert queries (which you currently do). Try it with the exact query I provided, it should work and have an incrementing id which is unique for each user. If you use a different type of id (say, UUID), you would have to generate that by yourself and include it in the query.

Comment: Than the id is always 0 like before.

Comment: `CREATE TABLE users (id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, username VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE, password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, email VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);` try creating your table like this and using my query.

Comment: Thanks, now it works. It was a wrong table setup. One last question: Do you know a good article about creating the UUID. Because logically I have to get all the existing ids first and then creating the UUID, to get sure there is no duplicate. And I think that takes a way to long.

Comment: Never had to implement this in raw PHP, but theoretically there is still a chance that 2 uuid's will be the same, even though it's very slim. I found this which might be useful: https://github.com/ramsey/uuid